# How can I add a button to the right side of an antd menu item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, antd

I want to create a Sider in React with antd. I fill the sider dynamically with items. Therefore I have the function getItem() to create me an item. Now I want to add a button next to the label of the item to delete this item. Unfortunally I did't found a way to deal with this.

```
const result= data.map(address => getItem(address.name, address.id, <ContactsOutlined />));

function getItem(
    label: React.ReactNode,
    key: React.Key,
    icon?: React.ReactNode,
    children?: MenuItem[],
): MenuItem {
    return { key, icon, children, label, } as MenuItem;
}


<Menu
  onClick={clickMenu}
  theme="dark"
  mode="inline"
  items={items}
/>
```